# Unable to see Django page

Tags: python, django, system-administration

I have a django site that is deployed in production and already ran `python manage.py runserver` and so now the server is running on the port of `8000`.

So what I want to do is to hit the running server and visited this on the domain `domainname.com:8000` and am not getting any response from the server.

Should I be doing something else? Very noob sysadmin here.

Note: Already set `debug=False` and `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['domain.com']`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have a django site that is deployed in production and already ran python manage.py runserver

That's not how you deploy Django projects in production, cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/

The builtin dev server is only made for dev - it's unsafe, doesn't handle concurrent requests etc.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to @bruno desthuilliers answer, with which I totally agree, if nevertheless you insist, you have to run the server as:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

so that to let it listen to any interface.

Relevant documentation: [django-admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port).